# Why SwiftUI context menu show all row view in preview?

Tags: ios, swiftui, contextmenu, swiftui-list

I have a complex view in List row:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                FullWidthImageView(ad)

                HStack {
                    Text("\(self.price) \(self.ad.currency!)")
                            .font(.headline)
                    Spacer()
                    SwiftUI.Image(systemName: "heart")
                }
                        .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 10.0)
```

Where `FullWidthImageView` is view with defined contexMenu modifier.
But when I long-press on an image I see not the only image in preview, but all row view.

[image]
[image]

There is no other contextMenu on any element.

How to make a preview in context with image only?

UPD. [Here](https://gist.github.com/tfedyanin/d0691ebbcaddb2b4bef943d35e8ee202) is a simple code illustrating the problem

Comment: show us FullWidthImageView

Comment: FullWidthImageView its image itself (upper price and heart button)

Comment: it is view, where you defined contextMenu, isn't it?

Comment: I create [gist](https://gist.github.com/tfedyanin/d0691ebbcaddb2b4bef943d35e8ee202) with illustration of problem (based on @asperi answer)

Comment: OK, I finally have got, what you are talking about :-). unfortunately, this is list row standard behavior. there is some discussion at stackoverflow (gestures pass thru all components in list row)

Comment: try use ScrollView if you are able to. Even full functionality of List could be done this way (if you need it). see my updating answer

Answer (score 7):

We don't have any idea why in your case it doesn't work, until we see your FullWidthImageView and how you construct the context menu. Asperi's answer is working example, and it is correctly done! **But did it really explain your trouble?**

The trouble is that while applying `.contextMenu` modifier to only some part of your View (as in your example) we have to be careful.

Let see some example.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FullWidthImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = modelStore
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: model.toggle ? "pencil.and.outline" : "trash")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 200)
        }.contextMenu(ContextMenu {
            Button(action: {
                self.model.toggle.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text("toggle image to?")
                    Image(systemName: model.toggle ? "trash" : "pencil.and.outline")
                }
            }
            Button("No") {}
        })
    }
}

class Model:ObservableObject {
    @Published var toggle = false
}

let modelStore = Model()

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = modelStore
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FullWidthImageView()
            Text("Long press the image to change it").bold()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

while running, **the "context menu" modified View seems to be "static"**!

[image]

Yes, on long press, you see the trash image, even though it is updated properly while you dismiss the context view. **On every long press you see trash only!**

How to make it dynamic? I need that the image will be the same, as on my "main View!
**Here we have `.id` modifier**. Let see the difference!

First we have to update our model

```
class Model:ObservableObject {
    @Published var toggle = false
    var id: UUID {
        UUID()
    }
}
```

and next our View

```
FullWidthImageView().id(model.id)
```

Now it works as we expected.
[image]

For another example, where "standard" state / binding simply doesn't work check [SwiftUI hierarchical Picker with dynamic data crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082411/swiftui-hierarchical-picker-with-dynamic-data-crashes/60083331#60083331)

**UPDATE**

As a temporary workaround you can mimic List by ScrollView

```
import SwiftUI

struct Row: View {
    let i:Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "trash")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 200)
                .contextMenu(ContextMenu {
                    Button("A") {}
                    Button("B") {}
                })
            Text("I don’t want to show in preview because I don’t have context menu modifire").bold()
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0 ..< 20) { (i) in
                    VStack {
                        Divider()
                        Row(i: i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not optimal, but in your case it should work
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is other question, but what happens if you include `.onAppear{..}` in one of your context menu item, after that, always your `.onAppear{...}` method will be trigger, even if you don't entry in context menu. Any explanation for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code (simulated possible your scenario) that works, ie. only image is shown for context menu preview (tested with Xcode 11.3+).

[image]

```
struct FullWidthImageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("auto")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 200)
            .contextMenu(ContextMenu() {
                Button("Ok") {}
            })
    }
}

struct TestContextMenu: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                FullWidthImageView()

                HStack {
                    Text("100 $")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "heart")
                }
                .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 10.0)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, check this https://gist.github.com/op183/208d86f213e25c4112bd0884b18878dc#file-gistfile1-txt do you have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Asperi, do you have an idea, why it doesn't "update" the image while the context menu is shown?

Comment: Asperi, check my own answer to OP question, and let me know ... :-)

Comment: @FedyanintTimofey, please check your link above - it references to some .js file.

Comment: @asperi , thank you for example, I tried it work correctly.
But my code use List and the problem is in it: https://gist.github.com/tfedyanin/d0691ebbcaddb2b4bef943d35e8ee202

Comment: Yes, @FedyanintTimofey, you're right - List changes behaviour, I missed mentioned List in your question, but it's not clear either this is a bug or a feature. Anyway, it worth submitting feedback to Apple. Or use ScrollView instead of List, where everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's buried in the replies here, but the key discovery is that `List` is changing the behavior of `.contextMenu` -- it creates "blocks" that pop up with the menu instead of attaching the menu to the element specified.  Switching out `List` for `ScrollView` fixes the issue.