# SwiftUI and multiple pickers

Tags: swiftui

Im trying to bind two pickers based on their selections... One picker is a static list... Then I'd also like to reproduce these pickers for someone to make a choice based on the ifrst one.

However, when one item is picked on the first one,  I want the second one to reflect that and change the items in the Picker.

I tried using a ObservableObject but when it came to multiple views of the same type, every picker was getting the same ObservableObject.

Here's some code..

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class section_array: ObservableObject {
let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
var first_value = 0 { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }
var second_value = 0 { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @Binding var master_sections: [ContentView.my_Section]
    @ObservedObject private var first_value: section_array = section_array()
   // @Binding var current_section: ContentView.my_Section
    @State private var comment: String = String()
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Picker(selection: self.$first_value.first_value , label: Text("Subsection")) {
                 ForEach(0 ..< self.master_sections.count) {
                 Text(self.master_sections[$0].name)
                       }}
                 TextField("Enter your comment.", text: $comment)

                   }
                  }                
                }
```

I attempt to access it here:

```
ForEach(master_subsections) { result in
      SwiftUIView(master_sections: self.$subsections)
                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329428/swiftui-hierarchical-picker-with-dynamic-data/60338770#60338770 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082411/swiftui-hierarchical-picker-with-dynamic-data-crashes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI hierarchical Picker with dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329428/swiftui-hierarchical-picker-with-dynamic-data)