# Disable a segment in a SwiftUI SegmentedPickerStyle Picker?

Tags: swiftui, uisegmentedcontrol

My SwiftUI app has a segmented Picker and I want to be able to disable one or more options depending on availability of options retrieved from a network call. The View code looks something like:

```
    @State private var profileMetricSelection: Int = 0
    private var profileMetrics: [RVStreamMetric] = [.speed, .heartRate, .cadence, .power, .altitude]
    @State private var metricDisabled = [true, true, true, true, true]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2.0) {
            ...(some views)...
            Picker(selection: $profileMetricSelection, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< profileMetrics.count) { index in
                    Text(self.profileMetrics[index].shortName).tag(index)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            ...(some more views)...
        }
    }
```

What I want to be able to do is modify the `metricDisabled` array based on network data so the view redraws enabling the relevant segments. In UIKit this can be done by calls to `setEnabled(_:forSegmentAt:)` on the UISegmentedControl but I can't find a way of doing this with the SwiftUI Picker

I know I can resort to wrapping a UISegmentedControl in a UIViewRepresentable but before that I just wanted to check I'm not missing something...

Comment: Not now. Use `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: you better filer profileMetrics based on boolean flag (so don't show the option, if it is unavailable)

Comment: @Asperi you could mimic that, the only trouble is visual style :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this simple trick

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 0
    let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    let disabled = [2, 3] // at index 2, 3
    var body: some View {

        let binding = Binding<Int>(get: {
            self.selection
        }) { (i) in
            if self.disabled.contains(i) {} else {
                self.selection = i
            }
        }

        return VStack {
            Picker(selection: binding, label: Text("label")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< data.count) { (i) in
                    Text("\(self.data[i])")
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Maybe something like

```
ForEach(0 ..< data.count) { (i) in
    if !self.disabled.contains(i) {
        Text("\(self.data[i])")
    } else {
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

could help to visualize it better

[image]

NOTES (based on the discussion)

From user perspective, the Picker is one control, which could be in disabled  / enabled state.

The option selected from Picker is not control, it is some value. If you make a list of controls presented to the user, some of them could be disabled, just to inform the user, that the action associated with it is not currently available (like menu, some buttons collection etc.)

I suggest you to show in Picker only values which could be selected. This collection of values could be updated any time.

**UPDATE**

Do you like something like this?

[image]

No problem at all ... (copy - paste - try - modify ...)

```
import SwiftUI

struct Data: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let value: Int
    var disabled: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = -1
    @State var data = [Data(id: 0, value: 10, disabled: true), Data(id: 1, value: 20, disabled: true), Data(id: 2, value: 3, disabled: true), Data(id: 3, value: 4, disabled: true), Data(id: 4, value: 5, disabled: true)]
    var filteredData: [Data] {
        data.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
            item.disabled == false
        })
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Select from avaialable")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.top)
                HStack {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Picker(selection: self.$selection, label: Text("label")) {
                            ForEach(self.filteredData) { (item) in
                                Text("\(item.value.description)").tag(item.id)
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                        .frame(width: CGFloat(self.filteredData.count) * proxy.size.width / CGFloat(self.data.count), alignment: .topLeading)

                        Spacer()
                    }.frame(height: 40)
                }.padding()
            }.background(Color.yellow.opacity(0.2)).cornerRadius(20)
            Button(action: {
                (0 ..< self.data.count).forEach { (i) in
                    self.data[i].disabled = false
                }
            }) {
                Text("Enable all")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.data[self.selection].disabled = true
                self.selection = -1
            }) {
                Text("Disable selected")
            }.disabled(selection < 0)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This violates Apple Human Interface Guidelines and behaves confusing. That's why I do not suggest such things (though, for the truth, I tried similar approach). So for now `UISegmentedControl` is preferable if segment disabling feature is needed.

Comment: @Asperi yes, we need all this xxxStyle protocols to be publicly available. or you can use spacer as temporary replacement in ForEach

Comment: Thanks both for the ideas, some imaginative thoughts there. It feels like a major update to SwiftUI is needed to bring the functionality closer to the level of UIKit, but I’m not sure if or when we will get that. In the meantime I think I will need to revert to UISegmentedControl to get it looking and behaving just right

Comment: @FleetPhil I personally will filter all "disabled" options out of picker. I like to see something is in "disabled state" only if user can enable it by some interaction, like temporary disabled login button till credentials are filled in etc. Disabled option in picker seem to be wrong idea for me.

Comment: @user3441734 I can see the logic of this approach.The way the app works is to present the view, and asynchronously get the data types that can be selected from the picker, but in some cases not all of the full list of types are available to be selected. Maybe a better approach is to display a placeholder for the picker until the options are available then only populate segments in the picker that are valid. I’ll give that a go...

Comment: @FleetPhil you can populate segments dynamically, what's the trouble? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60083331/3441734

Comment: My problem is not quite the same as that - when my view is initially constructed I don't know which of the Picker options are valid - so my original approach was that all of them are disabled initially and the valid ones are enabled when the async call returns. This means that on the first call I can't construct a Picker with just the valid options as there are none in the array and therefore no valid value for 'selection'.

Comment: @FleetPhil answer updated ... i hope that i've got what do you need

Comment: the trick in the beginning is mind blowing, but works :)