# SwiftUI | Access PickerView selection from another SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode11.4, pickerview

I tired to build a multicomponent picker based on [user3441734 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60083331/13175606) for a dynamic picker. This picker lives in its own .swift file. I can’t figure out how to save the selection in a variable to access it from another view again.

Here is my code so far. I marked my wrong solution with an  and its error message below.

```
import SwiftUI
struct DynamicPicker: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    // var to store the selection
    @State var selection: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            GeometryReader { geometry in

                HStack {

                    Picker(selection: self.$model.selectedManufacturer, label: Text("")){
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.model.manufacturerNames.count){ index in
                            Text(self.model.manufacturerNames[index])
                        }
                    }.labelsHidden()
                        .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width * CGFloat(0.3333))
                        .clipped()

                    Picker(selection: self.$model.selectedStock, label: Text("")){
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.model.stockNamesCount){ index in
                            Text(self.model.stockNames[index])
                        }
                    }
                    .id(self.model.id)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width * CGFloat(0.6666))
                    .clipped()
                }
            }

            // Show selection
            Text("\(self.model.manufacturerNames[model.selectedManufacturer])-\(self.model.stockNames[model.selectedStock])")

            // Save selection to variable 
            selection = "\(self.model.manufacturerNames[model.selectedManufacturer])-\(self.model.stockNames[model.selectedStock])"
        }
    }
}
```

*Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols*

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed additional selection, because the selection is already stored in model, so

1) remove these lines

```
@State var selection: String = ""

// Save selection to variable 
selection = "\(self.model.manufacturerNames[model.selectedManufacturer])-\(self.model.stockNames[model.selectedStock])"
```

2) don't create inline model, just declare it to be able to inject via constructor

```
struct DynamicPicker: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model  // << here !!
```

3) use same model for `DynamicPicker` that other dependent view, let's suppose it is called `ManufacturerView` (having declared the same observed model as above). And there is some root view holding both, so it could be as

```
struct RootView: View {
    let model = Model() // << create it here

    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        DynamicPicker(model: self.model)
        ManufacturerView(model: self.model)
      }
    }
}
```

so when selection is updated in `DynamicPicker` then `ManufacturerView` will be updated automatically with corresponding selection, cause use same data source.